# Can we interpret the Fourier transform of binomial coefficients as a random walk ?

Tags: combinatorics, fourier-analysis, binomial-coefficients, fourier-transform

We know that:

1. binomial coefficients $\tbinom {n}{k}$ will approach normal distribution in the limit.
2. binomial coefficients can be interpreted as a one-dimensional random walk.
3. Fourier transform of a standard normal distribution is a standard normal distribution.

My questions are:

Q1: Before we take the limit for binomial coefficients, that is, for finite (discrete) binomial coefficients $\tbinom {n}{k}$, if we take discrete Fourier transform(DFT) of it, can we interpret the result of each step for such DFT as another one-dimensional random walk ?

In a broader sense, I am trying to seek "deep" connection between one-dimensional random walk with Fourier transform. What are such "deep" connection ?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a proof that $\Bbb P\{\exists k > 0, X_k = 0\} = 1$ using the Fourier transform (I don't remember the details but I can search if you are interested).

Comment: [Here](http://hongler.org/lattice-models/lattice-models-master.pdf) is the proof.

Comment: @N.H.  Thank you for the reply.  My main question is, for finite (discrete) binomial coefficients $\tbinom {n}{k}$, if we take discrete Fourier transform(DFT) of it, can we interpret the result of each step for such DFT as another one-dimensional random walk ?